# retrieve partitions/batches from pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I need to collect partitions/batches from a big pyspark dataframe so that I can feed them into a neural network iteratively

My idea was to 1) partition the data, 2) Iteratively collect each partition, 3) transform the collected partition with `toPandas()`

I am a bit confused with methods like `foreachPartition` and `mapPartitions` because I can't iterate on them. Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `mapPartitions` to map each partition into list of elements and get them in iterative way using `toLocalIterator`:

```
for partition in rdd.mapPartitions(lambda part: [list(part)]).toLocalIterator():
    print(len(partition)) # or do something else :-)
```

Comment: I've been looking for this solution the entire day. Thanks