# Processing Pyspark RDD Partitions as Numpy on Worker Node

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark

Is it possible to partition a dataframe, then convert the dataframe partitions to numpy  in parallel and use them e.g. for training some learners from Scikit learn?

For example I tried this, but I got an index error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

```
def files_to_numpy(data):
  data_np = np.array(data)
  X = data_np[:, [0, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]]
  y = data_np[:,1]
data.rdd.map(files_to_numpy)
```

If I wanted to process the data on the driver I would have to run `collect()` after the conversion and then use the indexing syntax, but I want to run this in parallel on the workers (and ideally all the following training steps as well, leading to several trained instances of the learner).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data.rdd.mapPartitions(func)` which will be executed for each partition on the workers. It looks like you are using the rdd api which is very low level and difficult to use. I would advise you to use the Dataframe api which is safer and easier.

There you can achieve the same thing with

```
df.foreachPartition(func)
```

[pySpark forEachPartition - Where is code executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654982/pyspark-foreachpartition-where-is-code-executed)