# Can the memory/compute capacity of the python instance setup by spark executors in PySpark be controlled

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698201/9088594), python instances are set up when `foreachPartition`, `mapPartitions` functions are used in the nodes where the executors run. How are the memory / compute capacities of these instances set? Do we get to control it through some configuration?

Comment: Like all other [configuration properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)?

Comment: @mazaneicha, The closest property in the list that comes to mentioning this is ```spark.executor.pyspark.memory``` but even here, in the description, it does not explicitly mention if this is for the python instances created by the executor. Also, is there a similar parameter for cores?

Comment: python will be able to use all `spark.executor.cores` cores.